# Question concerning the proof of the Ergodentheorem by Birkhoff

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu,T)$ be an ergodic dynamical system and $f\in L_{\mu}^1$. Then it is a.s.
> >     $$
> > \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^k=\int f\, d\mu.
> > $$

Now I am trying to understand the proof of this.

Here is one point I do not understand.

For $\varepsilon > 0$ define 
$$
E:=\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^k>\varepsilon\right\}.
$$
Now the proof says: It's obvious that $E$ is $T$-invariant.

For me it's not obvious. Can you explain me why $E$ is $T$-invariant, i.e. why
$$
T^{-1}(E)=E\text{ a.s.}?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assume that $x\in E$, and we will prove that $T(x)\in E$ as well, so that $x\in T^{-1}(E)$. By definition, $$\varepsilon<\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^k(x) = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}f(x) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\circ T^{k}(T(x)).$$ Of course $\frac{1}{n}f(x)\to 0$ for almost every $x$, so the right hand side of this expression is just$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\circ T^k(T(x)) = \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}f\circ T^k(T(x)).$$ In the limit $(n-1)/n\to 1$, leaving us with $$ = \limsup_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} f\circ T^k(T(x)).$$ This proves that $T(x)\in E$.

Next assume that $x\in T^{-1}(E)$, and we will prove that $x\in E$. By definition $T(x)\in E$, so $$\varepsilon<\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^k(T(x)) = \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^{k+1}(x).$$ Similar to before, we rewrite the sum on the right hand side as $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^{k+1}(x) = -\frac{f(x)}{n} + \frac{n+1}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\circ T^k(x).$$ Since $f(x)/n\to 0$ for almost every $x$ and $(n+1)/n\to 1$, we see that $$\varepsilon<\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^{k+1}(x) = \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\circ T^k(x) = \limsup_{m\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}f\circ T^m(x).$$ Therefore, $x\in E$.

Comment: Why is $f(x)/n\to 0$ a.s.?

Comment: For any real number $r\in \mathbb{R}$, you have $r/n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. For almost every $x\in\Omega$, the value $f(x)$ is finite, i.e., is a real number, so $f(x)/n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. The reason $f(x)$ is finite for almost every $x$ is because we are assuming $f\in L^1$.

Comment: Ah, it is $\int\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu <\infty\implies \lvert f\rvert<\infty$ a.s. $\Leftrightarrow f<\infty$ a.s.. So $f(x)/n\not\to 0$ for $x\in\left\{f=\infty\right\}$, this is a set of measure 0.

Comment: Exactly, perfect!

Comment: Then the identity $T^{-1}(E)=E$ is not only a.s. but surely?

Comment: Well, unfortunately you can't really say that, because the set $E$ itself is only defined up to a set of measure $0$!  (because $f$ is only defined up to a set of measure $0$)

Comment: Ähm, why is $f$ only defined up to a set of measure 0? Sorry, when asking so much.

Comment: This is a definition thing: two functions $f,g\in L^1$ are considered equal if $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ has measure $0$. The reason for doing this is that otherwise the $L^1$-norm would not actually be a norm, since it would not be positive definite. See, for instance, the wikipedia discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces).